# can't ssh into remote server ubuntu 16.04

Tags: ssh, digital-ocean, ubuntu-16.04, ubuntu-server

I have a digital ocean server that I am attempting to ssh into.

I run the command "ssh root@xx.xxx.xx.xxx"

and enter the password given to me from digital ocean.

The terminal will lag on the line after the password has been entered. It will not give any additional information. It will not say that the login has failed or anything, only stay on this line for what could be hours.

Where can I begin to diagnose this problem ?

Answer (score 0):

Couple of ideas: Is sshd enabled on this server? are external IPs allowed to ssh through firewall?

Comment: ok so i did some more digging on this and I found something else that should be worth noting. I have been using virtualbox to set up a VPN server. When I ssh into my servers WITHIN the VM, there is no problem and I can connect. However, when I try to ssh outside of the VM, that's when I run into the problem.. What did I do? Why is this acting this way?